# How to put 2 horizontal scroll bars in a v-data-table (Vue / vuetify)

Tags: html, css, vue.js, vuetify.js

What happens is that I am practicing Vue / Vuetify with the v-data-table, I was creating a table and I see that it has a horizontal scroll bar but it is at the bottom.
[image: Screenshot of my practice]

What I want to do now is to have 2 horizontal scroll bars, one at the bottom, which is the one created by default, and the other at the top of the table, both of which work to move through the information in the v-data-table (Screenshot edited)

[image: Screenshot edited of the result I want to do]

I tried to search for information but I only find for vainilla JS and HTML, but not in Vue / Vuetify

This is the code I use:

---

```
<template>
  <v-container>

     <v-data-table
    :headers="headers"
    :items="desserts"
    :items-per-page="5"
    class="elevation-1"
  ></v-data-table>

  </v-container>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    name: 'HelloWorld',

    data () {
      return {
        headers: [
          {
            text: 'Dessert (100g serving)',
            align: 'start',
            sortable: false,
            value: 'name',
            width: 300
          },
          { text: 'Calories', value: 'calories', width: 300},
          { text: 'Fat (g)', value: 'fat', width: 300 },
          { text: 'Carbs (g)', value: 'carbs', width: 300 },
          { text: 'Protein (g)', value: 'protein', width: 300 },
          { text: 'Iron (%)', value: 'iron', width: 300 },
        ],
        desserts: [
          {
            name: 'Frozen Yogurt',
            calories: 159,
            fat: 6.0,
            carbs: 24,
            protein: 4.0,
            iron: '1%',
          },
          {
            name: 'Ice cream sandwich',
            calories: 237,
            fat: 9.0,
            carbs: 37,
            protein: 4.3,
            iron: '1%',
          },
          {
            name: 'Eclair',
            calories: 262,
            fat: 16.0,
            carbs: 23,
            protein: 6.0,
            iron: '7%',
          },
          {
            name: 'Cupcake',
            calories: 305,
            fat: 3.7,
            carbs: 67,
            protein: 4.3,
            iron: '8%',
          },
          {
            name: 'Gingerbread',
            calories: 356,
            fat: 16.0,
            carbs: 49,
            protein: 3.9,
            iron: '16%',
          },
          {
            name: 'Jelly bean',
            calories: 375,
            fat: 0.0,
            carbs: 94,
            protein: 0.0,
            iron: '0%',
          },
          {
            name: 'Lollipop',
            calories: 392,
            fat: 0.2,
            carbs: 98,
            protein: 0,
            iron: '2%',
          },
          {
            name: 'Honeycomb',
            calories: 408,
            fat: 3.2,
            carbs: 87,
            protein: 6.5,
            iron: '45%',
          },
          {
            name: 'Donut',
            calories: 452,
            fat: 25.0,
            carbs: 51,
            protein: 4.9,
            iron: '22%',
          },
          {
            name: 'KitKat',
            calories: 518,
            fat: 26.0,
            carbs: 65,
            protein: 7,
            iron: '6%',
          },
        ],
      }
    },
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to find a result.

What should be done is to generate 3 CSS methods, one for the size of the scrollbar path, another for the size of the scrollbar and another to make the scrollbar visible and functional.

Then in export default of the component the mounted section is added and a method is inserted, that what it does is to tell it that the position of my top scrollbar will be the same as the bottom one and vice versa.

To reference the top scrollbar I use the wrapper2 tag, and to reference the v-data-table scrollbar it is necessary to make 2 references, one to the tag with which the v-data-table will be identified and another one that refers to the same v-data-table component.

And what is the hmtl it is only necessary to make a reference between the scroll bar and the v-data-table.

[image: Final Result]

This is de updated coded:

```
<template>
  <v-container>
    
    <v-col>
        <!-- we use this wrapper to show the second scroll above of table -->
        <div id="wrapper2">
          <div id="div2" class="width-scroll" >
          </div>
        </div>
    </v-col>
    
<v-col>
     <v-data-table
    :headers="headers"
    :items="desserts"
    :items-per-page="5"
    class="elevation-1 table-reference"
  ></v-data-table>
</v-col>

  </v-container>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    name: 'HelloWorld',

    data () {
      return {
        headers: [
          {
            text: 'Dessert (100g serving)',
            align: 'start',
            sortable: false,
            value: 'name',
            width: 300
          },
          { text: 'Calories', value: 'calories', width: 300},
          { text: 'Fat (g)', value: 'fat', width: 300 },
          { text: 'Carbs (g)', value: 'carbs', width: 300 },
          { text: 'Protein (g)', value: 'protein', width: 300 },
          { text: 'Iron (%)', value: 'iron', width: 300 },
        ],
        desserts: [
          {
            name: 'Frozen Yogurt',
            calories: 159,
            fat: 6.0,
            carbs: 24,
            protein: 4.0,
            iron: '1%',
          },
          {
            name: 'Ice cream sandwich',
            calories: 237,
            fat: 9.0,
            carbs: 37,
            protein: 4.3,
            iron: '1%',
          },
          {
            name: 'Eclair',
            calories: 262,
            fat: 16.0,
            carbs: 23,
            protein: 6.0,
            iron: '7%',
          },
          {
            name: 'Cupcake',
            calories: 305,
            fat: 3.7,
            carbs: 67,
            protein: 4.3,
            iron: '8%',
          },
          {
            name: 'Gingerbread',
            calories: 356,
            fat: 16.0,
            carbs: 49,
            protein: 3.9,
            iron: '16%',
          },
          {
            name: 'Jelly bean',
            calories: 375,
            fat: 0.0,
            carbs: 94,
            protein: 0.0,
            iron: '0%',
          },
          {
            name: 'Lollipop',
            calories: 392,
            fat: 0.2,
            carbs: 98,
            protein: 0,
            iron: '2%',
          },
          {
            name: 'Honeycomb',
            calories: 408,
            fat: 3.2,
            carbs: 87,
            protein: 6.5,
            iron: '45%',
          },
          {
            name: 'Donut',
            calories: 452,
            fat: 25.0,
            carbs: 51,
            protein: 4.9,
            iron: '22%',
          },
          {
            name: 'KitKat',
            calories: 518,
            fat: 26.0,
            carbs: 65,
            protein: 7,
            iron: '6%',
          },
        ],
      }
    },
    
    mounted(){
      let wrapper_1 = document.querySelector('.table-reference .v-data-table__wrapper');
      let wrapper_2 = document.querySelector('#wrapper2');
      wrapper_1.onscroll = function() {
        wrapper_2.scrollLeft = wrapper_1.scrollLeft;
      };
        
      wrapper_2.onscroll = function() {
        wrapper_1.scrollLeft = wrapper_2.scrollLeft;
      };
    },

  }
</script>

<style>

/* This is the size of the path of the scrollbar */
#wrapper2{
      width: 100%;
      overflow-x: scroll; 
      overflow-y:hidden;
  }

/* This div allow to make the scroll function and show the scrollbar */
  #div2 {
      height: 1px;
      overflow: scroll;
  }

  /* This is the size of the scrollbar */
  .width-scroll{
    width:1800px;
  }

</style>
```